# Why after installing vue CLI through npm 6.9.0 dosn't work?

Tags: vue.js, npm, command-line-interface

When i use this command bellow :

```
vue create hello-world
```

I got this message :

```
'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

After 1 month I still haven't found the solution..

**Some informations:**

- My OS : Windows 10
- NPM version : 6.9.0
- vue version : 2.6.10
- Vue cli installed version : @vue/cli@3.8.2

==>

- 0 error message when i installed all these packages.
- I correctly added npm path on environement variable.

Comment: did you intall vue-cli globally

Comment: yes, everything globally

Answer (score 2):

If you set the path correctly then you need to restart the system once because sometimes environment variables need restart after setting the path.

And Do this (If above not works):

Run command as administrator privileged.

```
npm install --global vue-cli
```

Set this path to environment variables:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

This one too:

[image: add]

In last, restart the cmd, system and run the vue again. It should work just fine.